# Why can't I use the open3d.ml.tf API after installing open3d?

Tags: open3d

I install open3d by "conda install -c open3d-admin open3d", but when I want to import the API like open3d.ml.tf, it shows 'open3d' has no attribute 'ml', although import open3d works well.

Do I need to build it with cmake? I am using windows, it is too complicated for me to build it with cmake and install it after building

Comment: What OS are you using?  Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

open3d-ml are not supported on Windows, you can use it on Ubuntu.